# setOnItemClickListener get invoke when hold for 3 seconds in Android

Tags: android, listview, timer

I'm trying to make some keen experiments about android event handler...

Let say.., I have a list which contains 5 items on it. and then I want to make those items become Clickable WHILE hold the item for 3 seconds(less than that it won't be clickable).

is that possible?

this some code for my list...

```
String[] projection = new String[] {Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID, 
                             Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, 
                             Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
String[] displayFields = new String[] {Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, 
                             Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, 
                             android.R.id.text2 };

Cursor cur = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, 
               projection, null, null, null);
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cur, 
               displayFields, displayViews));
```

OK that's it! I hope it's clear enough....
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and start a timer ON_DOWN and check to see if it expired ON_UP. If the timer was > 3 seconds fire of whatever event you want.

Android also has [longClicks/longPress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) built in which work a lot like this, minus controlling the exact duration of pressing but are super easy to implement. The benefit of the longPress is that it is used all over the OS which means users are very familier with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up by a TouchEventListener that fires a Timer for 3 secs later with the MotionEvent ACTION_DOWN

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
```

while MOTION_UP can cancel that same Timer.